# How to logout the user while the browser is closed in MVC?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have created an MVC asp.net project I have to save date time while the browser is closed. I tried the solution given before. A sample project would help me to understand how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way i implement. Use onbeforeunload event when tab is closing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.location.href = '/logout'; //your action to logout

    });
  };
</script>
```

or ajax call to logout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/logout",
        success: function (result) {
            //
        }
    });

    };
</script>
```

Comment: I tried to call log out but the method is not invoked while closing the browser

Comment: I tried it to call ajax post and it worked  @Hien Nguyen Thanks for the reply

Comment: while loading other page its logout how can i handle it?

Comment: if current url and new current url are different, it will be load new page, you can check it in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Well you could add `UserLastLoginDate` or `UserLastVistedDate` in user table

Then the next time the userOpen the page you validate `UserLastLoginDate` with current Datetime, and there you have how much time the brwoser have been closed.